php ffmpeg pipe multicast issue
I have four video in my server. I want to display all of them same page but video tag url is a php page.
Actually it is working. But when i tried to open new tab again index.php then display only 2 video. When waiting to long display all of them. Why i must to waiting and why server take long time to response? I have ubuntu 20.04 and 8gb ram. If you copy link and open it multiple tab same time you will see the issue.
Video Link is:
index.php
index.php
<html>
<video src="test.php?video_name=1.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" class="video"></video>
<video src="test.php?video_name=2.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" class="video"></video>
<video src="test.php?video_name=3.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" class="video"></video>
<video src="test.php?video_name=4.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" class="video"></video>
<html>

test.php
<?
$video_name=$_GET['video_name'];
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
passthru('ffmpeg -i '.$video_name.'.mp4 -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart -f mp4 pipe:');
exit();
?>

If close one of tab display all. I think ffmpeg or passthru function make  server busy. It must be opened all tab without waiting. It is very importing for me. I developed online camera view system and serving to html with passthru and ffmpeg. But if user open multiple tab server not responding or take long time.

I think it is a network IO resource issue (not related to programming / coding)

I think it rason may be browser phpsessid. Because when server not responding if open different browser server responding.

Why don't you just encode the videos once and save the result on the server, and serve the already encoded videos? Encoding them all on every single request is madness and will surly cause major issues quickly if you get any kind of traffic.

Beacuse all videos are live stream. I have 25 cameras. I want to only show them web page. No recording just stream. So i used to passthru and ffmpeg. May be i can try websocket to serve videos. But I'm sure this issue related to phpsessid. My server has apache.

The system completed and working fine on single page or multiple client same time. But if one client open multible tab not responding server to client. I want to solve this.

I found the issue. Chrome has a max of 6 sockets, so this stops any more media streams (HTML audio / video) from running and stopped to request to server. I hope maybe it will help someone.
